# How to center and fix my messed up web page?

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm trying to make this web page and it just has so many issues. I cannot center the #titlediv and the navbar sometimes disappears. I'm not gonna lie: it might be a big fix, I'm really not sure. But here's the link if anyone can possibly salvage it:

http://jsfiddle.net/glenohumeral13/c604vbrn/

Code:

```
<body>
    <div id="parallaxish"></div>
    <div id="navbar">
        <nav>
<a href="#item1">Item1</a>

<a href="#item2">Item2</a>

<a href="#item3">Item3</a>

        </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="contentdiv">
        <div id="welcome">
            <div id="titlediv">

<h1>Title will go here</h1>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="barrier"></div>
        <div id="item1">

<h1>Item1</h1>

        </div>
        <div class="barrier"></div>
        <div id="item2">

<h1>Item2</h1>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
#parallaxish {
    background-image: url('http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m54j1nIYN21r0k830o1_500.jpg');
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-position: center;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
#navbar {
    float:right;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-transition: color 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: color 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: color 1s ease-out;
    transition: color 1s ease-out;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
nav a:hover {
    color: #16a085;
}
#welcome {
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: black;
}
#welcome h1, #item1 h1, #item2 h1 {
    font-weight: 100;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
#titlediv {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    width: 180px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
.barrier {
    height: 120px;
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
}
#item1 {
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    color: #16a085;
}
#item1 h1, #item2 h1 {
    padding: 5% 0;
}
#item2 {
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: "_Code required by stackoverflow:_" :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a demo!
http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/c604vbrn/10/
What it looks like what you are trying to do is vertically and horizontally center it, in the div, correct?
There is a simple way to do this with css, that i find very useful:

```
<div id="welcome">
<div id="titlediv">
<h1>Title will go here</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

First of all, we give `position:relative;` to the div `id="welcome"`:

```
/*With your current CSS*/
#welcome {
height: 600px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
background-color: black;
position:relative;
}
```

And then, the magic! The `<div>` `id="titlediv"` is given `position:absolute;` and a few other rules:

```
#titlediv {
border: 2px solid #fff;
width: 180px;
margin: auto;
padding: auto auto;
position: absolute;
width: 180px;
height: 76px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top:0;
bottom:0;
overflow: auto;
}
```

This little trick only works if the width and height are declared.
Now, for the nav bar easily fixed:

```
#navbar {
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:100px;
height: 30px;
z-index:10;
}
```

And to wrap it all up, a full screen demo!
http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/c604vbrn/10/embedded/result/

Comment: I really want to thank you for not only putting so much work and thought into your post, but also for being genuinely helpful and nice. Have a great day!

Comment: It was my pleasure! Make sure you mark it as accepted, so if others later need it, it will be at the top of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

http://stickyjs.com/ will help you!
I

```
//LOAD THE FILES
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.sticky.js"></script>

/RUN THE SCRIPT
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#navbar").sticky({topSpacing:0});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

if i were in your place i'll try to make my page by using a framework like bootstrap or foundation , if you want a lightweight one you can always try skeleton is easy to use & you can find snippets around the web very easily :

---

http://getbootstrap.com/ |
http://bootsnipp.com/

---

hopefully i helped you & next time try using **google** first

Comment: I've tried for hours. I can't find anything that doesn't add another problem. And asking on other sites provokes rude people, so I figured this would be the most helpful. I would like to not use Bootstrap, just because I never quite understand framework websites like I do ones I built from the ground up.

Comment: well glad that you found your solution , and sorry if i wasn't abig help for you !!